# How many ways could one paint their nails with 7 nail varnish colours

Tags: combinatorics

The problem goes like this: you have 7 colours of nail polish and 10 fingers. You're not coordinated enough to use more than one colour on each nail, but aren't fussed about using different colours on different nails. How many ways can you paint the nails on your hands if you are not worried about whether they match?

According to the multiplication principle: The number of ways of making a sequence of independent choices is the product of the number of choices at each step.

Therefore, I would have 70 ways in which to paint my nails.
Is this correct?

Many thanks, Alex

Comment: There are $7$ choices per finger, so $7^{10}$.

Comment: Thank you, Lulu